# Why is IE11 giving me an error for node-fetch using fetch in the node modules folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, isomorphic-fetch-api

My React site isn’t loading in IE11 because the node-fetch module uses fetch in the node module folder browser.js file. Although I’m not using node-fetch outside of node, IE is giving me an error because of the fetch being used in that browser.js file.  If I import isomorphic-fetch into the node module file it works, but altering the file is not ideal.  It also works if I import isomorphic-fetch in app.js, but it seems like I’m missing something.

Why is IE giving me an error?

Comment: `node-fetch` doesn't work in browsers at all. It's explicitly a client for Node.js, not browsers. You need to look for a fetch polyfill

Comment: Strange because I am using it in node only, so why would IE have a problem with it.

Comment: Your edits changed this quite a bit. I think you need to share some code that fails on IE11 for you.

Comment: The error in IE points directly to the fetch in the browser.js file in the node-fetch folder in the node modules folder.